# Why is solving $ax + by = c$ for $x$ and $y$ equivalent to solving $ax \equiv c$ (mod $b$), wherein $a, b, c, x, y \in\mathbb Z$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I am learning about modular equations. In my math textbook it says "For the  diophantine equation $ax + by = c$, $a, b, c \neq 0$. To find which integers $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equation, the equality can be reformulated to a congruence: Determine $x$ so that $ax \equiv c$ (mod $b$)."

I don't see why it is possible to rewrite $ax + by = c$ to $ax \equiv c$ (mod $b$) when solving the diophantine equation. Why is this possible?

Comment: See the equation ax+by=c mod b

Comment: Try to explain what $a x \equiv c\  (\mod b)$ means.

Comment: @Gribouillis Literally, ax ≡ c (mod b) means that "ax is congruent to c, modulus b". In other words, the remainder of ax/b is equal to the remainder of c/b.

Comment: In simple words, it means that $a x - c$ is a multiple of $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $ax \equiv c \pmod b$, it must mean that $ax-c$ is divisible by $b$, so that:
$$ax - c = kb \implies ax-kb = c$$
And if $ax+by=c$, then obviously $ax \equiv c \pmod b$, so the equations are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

This answer serves as a summary and elaboration of Elie Louis answer.

$$\eqalign{
  & ax \equiv c\left( {\bmod b} \right) \Leftrightarrow ax\bmod b = c\bmod b  \cr 
  & ax = pb + r{\rm{ }} \wedge {\rm{ }}c = qb + r  \cr 
  & ax - c = pb + r - qb - r = pb - qb = b(p - q) = kb,{\rm{ }}k = p - q \Rightarrow b|(ax - c)  \cr 
  & ax - kb = c \Leftrightarrow ax + by,{\rm{ }}y =  - k  \cr 
  & a,b,c,k,p,q,x,y \in {{\bf{Z}}^*} \cr} $$